# Blazor Server Cannot send data if the connection is not in the 'Connected' State

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

In my Blazor project, I'm using two `_Host.cshtml` files. The first one is the default `_Host.cshtml` file. Another one is used to giving anonymous login access to a specific `.razor` page. Let's say that the anonymous razor page is `x.razor`.

x.razor

```cs
@page '\PublicRazor\x'
...
```

First Scenario

> I'm going to `x.razor` page without login. In this case, none of the functions in `x.razor` are working (like button click, form validation). When I check the developer console, I saw this
> [image]

Second Scenario

> I'm goign to `x.razor` page after login to blazor app. In this case, all of the functions in `x.razor` are woking correctly. And developer console haven't any errors.

Why is this happenning? How to bring `x.razor`'s all functions to woking state?

Default _Host.cshtml

```cs
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@namespace has.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@attribute [Authorize]
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>has</title>
    <base href="~/" />
    <link href="_content/Blazor.ContextMenu/blazorContextMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/js/site.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <app>
        <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="Server" />
    </app>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/Blazor.ContextMenu/blazorContextMenu.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Other _Host.cshtml (Used to give anonymous access to `x.razor`)

```cs
@page "/publicrazor"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@namespace has.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@attribute [AllowAnonymous]
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>has</title>
    <base href="~/publicrazor" />
    <link href="_content/Blazor.ContextMenu/blazorContextMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/js/site.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <app>
        <component type="typeof(PublicApp)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
    </app>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/Blazor.ContextMenu/blazorContextMenu.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Startup.cs

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
       endpoints.MapControllers();
       endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
       endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
       endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("~/PublicRazor/{**segment}", "/PublicRazor/_Host");
    });
```

Comment: "Cannot send data if the connection is not in the 'Connected' State" is not the interesting error. This happens when you try to do an action needing Blazor response while the connection ended because of some other Error/Exception. You must focus on the first error.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine I can't find any other error. This is the only error that I could see

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, that error is not the **interesting** one. In order to find the interesting error, you have to turn on `DetailedErrors` and you can do this in your `appsettings.Development.json` file.

```json
{
  "DetailedErrors": true,
  ... the rest of your settings here
}
```

Once you turn this on and restart your application, the browser Console should reveal the root cause error(s) that triggered this vague error.